# T-SQL Average of Table Subset

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table (in SQL Server 2005) of daily weather data for a single location which includes these columns:

```
LogDate                 DATETIME  
HighTemp                INT  
Temp6MonthHighAverage   INT
```

`LogDate` and `HighTemp` have data. `HighTemp6MonthAverage` will be populated with, as the name suggests, the average high temperature for the 6 months ending in `LogDate`.

There are similar requirements for LowTemp, as well as humidity and several other items, for data spanning decades.

I find myself thinking in circles.  Can I derive this average for each row in an UPDATE statement using set operations, or do I need to implement a solution with cursors? I will appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You can do it with an `UPDATE` statement, but I suspect that it might be more efficient to use a cursor due to the fact that SQL Server probably can't do a rolling average.

Comment: What version of SQL server please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-- select 
select HighTemp, LogDate,(select AVG(HighTemp) 
                          from tbl where 
                          DATEDIFF(MONTH, LogDate, t1.LogDate) between 0 and 6)
from tbl t1

-- update
update t1 set Temp6MonthHighAverage = (select AVG(HighTemp) 
                          from tbl where 
                          DATEDIFF(MONTH, LogDate, t1.LogDate) between 0 and 6)
from tbl t1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this with a simple UPDATE:

```
UPDATE table SET Temp6MonthHighAverage = 
  (SELECT AVG(HighTemp) FROM table t2 WHERE
     t2.LogDate <= table.LogDate
     AND t2.LogDate > DATEADD(m, -6, table.LogDate)
  )
```

To avoid re-calculating constantly (since the past will not change), just add a `WHERE Temp6MonthHighAverage IS NULL` at the end and the same UPDATE can be run as needed to fill in the gaps as new dates are added.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at something like this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
    LogDate DATETIME,
    HighTemp INT,
    Temp6MonthHighAverage INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '01 Jan 2000', 15, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '01 May 2000', 14, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '01 Jun 2000', 13, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '01 Jul 2000', 12, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '01 Dec 2000', 17, NULL

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table

;WITH DistinctDates AS (
        SELECT  DATEADD(month,-6,LogDate) StartDate,
                LogDate EndDate,
                HighTemp
        FROM    @Table
)
, Aggregates AS (
        SELECT  dd.EndDate LogDate,
                dd.HighTemp,
                MAX(t.HighTemp) Temp6MonthHighAverage
        FROM    DistinctDates dd LEFT JOIN
                @Table t    ON  t.LogDate BETWEEN dd.StartDate AND dd.EndDate
        GROUP BY    dd.EndDate,
                    dd.HighTemp
)
UPDATE  @Table
SET     Temp6MonthHighAverage = a.Temp6MonthHighAverage
FROM    @Table t INNER JOIN
        Aggregates a    ON  t.LogDate = a.LogDate

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table
```